# Search/filter only values that match an allowed combination

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a dataframe like so:

```py
  ID  Toes
0  1  []
1  2  ['LF1', 'LF2']
2  4  ['LF1']
3  4  ['LF2']
4  5  ['LF1', 'LF4', 'RR1', 'RR2']
5  6  []
6  7  ['LF2', 'RF1', 'RF2']
7  8  ['LF1', 'LF2', 'LF3', 'LF4', 'LF5']
```

The `Toes` column is missing toes in lizards, they have 20 toes in total. I have a given individual, let's call it Si, and want to search for its possible matches. For example, this one has 2 toes missing:
`Si_toes = ['LF1', 'LF2']`.

How do I find all individuals where the only allowed missing toes are those of the current one, i.e. ['LF1', 'LF2'] - but no other missing values are allowed?

The expected result should be:

```py
# for Si where Si_toes = ['LF1', 'LF2']
0  1  []
1  2  ['LF1', 'LF2']
2  4  ['LF1']
3  4  ['LF2']
5  6  []
```

I tried

```py
toes = ['LF1', 'LF2']
df.loc[df.Toes.apply(lambda x: bool(set(x).intersection( list(toes) )))]
```

But this returns all that have ['LF1', 'LF2'] in them, so it includes these ones below, which I don't want.

```py
4  5  ['LF1', 'LF4', 'RR1', 'RR2']
6  7  ['LF2', 'RF1', 'RF2']
7  8  ['LF1', 'LF2', 'LF3', 'LF4', 'LF5']
```

Also tried:

```py
toes = ['LF1', 'LF2']
df.loc[df.Toes.map(set(['LF1', 'LF2']).issubset)]
```

But this returns all rows that include ['LF1', 'LF2'], so it returns these, which we don't want:

```py
1  2  ['LF1', 'LF2']
7  8  ['LF1', 'LF2', 'LF3', 'LF4', 'LF5']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all allowed missing toes from each row and check if the resulting set size is zero:

```
toes = ['LF1', 'LF2']
df.loc[df['Toes'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x) - set(toes)) == 0)]
```

Result:

```
    ID  Toes
0   1   []
1   2   [LF1, LF2]
2   3   [LF1]
3   4   [LF2]
5   6   []
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
>>df[df['Toes'].apply(lambda toe: set(toes).intersection(set(toe)) == set(toes))]
  ID        Toes
1  2  [LF1, LF2]
```

Comment: Thank you, but that returns the same as df.loc[df.Toes.map(set(['LF1', 'LF2']).issubset)], which is all the rows that have 'LF1', 'LF2' in them, regardless of whether there are other missing values. This reminds me I need to edit my question, so thank you :)